# Match and split by regular expression from start of string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, racket, parser-combinators

I'm trying to make a terminal parser (for a parser combinator) from scratch. My approach is to use `regexp-match-positions*` on the input string and if the pattern is found at the first position, then we output the split string.

This is what I've got, so far:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/match)

(define (make-terminal-parser pattern)
  (define (regexp-match-from-start pattern input)
    (match (regexp-match-positions* pattern input)
      [(list (cons 0 x) ...)
        (let ([index (car x)])
          (values (substring input 0 index)
                  (substring input index)))]

      [_ (error "Not found!")]))

  (lambda (input)
    (regexp-match-from-start pattern input)))

(define ALPHA (make-terminal-parser #rx"[a-zA-Z]"))

(ALPHA "hello")
```

My `ALPHA` doesn't seem to work and I think it's because of the pattern matching not equating with anything. In the REPL, `(regexp-match-positions* #rx"[a-zA-Z]" "hello")` outputs what I would expect (`'((0 . 1) (1 . 2) etc.)`), so I don't really understand why that doesn't match with `(list (cons 0 x) ...)`. If I change the regular expression to `#rx"h"`, then it correctly splits the string; but obviously this is too specific.

(On a related note: I don't understand why I need to `(car x)` to get the actual index value out of the matched cons.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem I was having was indeed with my pattern matching. I was attempting to match on `(list (cons 0 x) ...)`, but the documentation implies that will only match a list of one-or-more elements of `(0 . x)` (where `x` is arbitrary). That's not what I want.

Lists are a series of `cons`, so I changed my matching criteria to `(cons (cons 0 x) _)` and that gives me what I want.

That also explains why I had to `(car x)` in my previous attempt. The `x` match in `(list (cons 0 x) ...)` would have matched every righthand element of each `cons` in the list, so it would have returned a list. For example `'((0 . 1) (0 . 2) (0 . 3))` would have matched and `x` would equal `'(1 2 3)`.

So, my fixed code is:

```
(define (make-terminal-parser pattern)
  (define (regexp-match-from-start pattern input)
    (match (regexp-match-positions pattern input)
      [(cons (cons 0 index) _)
          (values (substring input 0 index)
                  (substring input index))]

      [_ (error "Not found!")]))

  (lambda (input)
    (regexp-match-from-start pattern input)))
```

n.b., I also don't need to use the starred version of `regexp-match-positions` with pattern matching, fwiw.